# Loop a calculation a certain fixed amount

Tags: java

Does anyone know how I can loop through this calculation 7 times?

```
    public static double[] getNumSeedsPerType(String[] treeTypes, int[] numTreesPerType, final double FIR_DIE) {

        double numSeeds = 0;
        double[] numSeedsPerType = new double[numTreesPerType.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < treeTypes.length; i++) {
            if (treeTypes[i].equalsIgnoreCase("fir")) {

                // This part of the calculation
                numSeeds = numTreesPerType[i] - (numTreesPerType[i] * FIR_DIE);
                numSeedsPerType[i] = numSeeds + numTreesPerType[i];
            }
        }

        return numSeedsPerType;
   }
```

Comment: Do you want to call the function 7 times? Just use a for loop that counts up to 7.

Comment: Use a for loop [0,7)?

Comment: I've tried using a for loop that loops from [0,7], but the result only returns the result after the first iteration

Comment: can you show us what you tried?

Comment: After the comment in the code, I added a for loop: for (int j = i; j < 7; j++) { numSeeds = numTreesPerType[i] - (numTreesPerType[i] * FIR_DIE); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding of your code is correct you can do the following:

- Use a for loop to do the calculation 7 times.
- Inside the loop change this code:

  ```
  numSeeds = numTreesPerType[i] - (numTreesPerType[i] * FIR_DIE);
  ```
- to this (so you can keep the results of every calculation):

  ```
  numSeeds += numTreesPerType[i] - (numTreesPerType[i] * FIR_DIE);
  ```

Comment: Well the code is supposed to take input of amount of trees to sell and then calculate the amount of seeds needed to be planted in order to reach that goal. However, we have to account that 7% of those planted seeds will die per year and it takes 7 years for a seed to become sellable. So more seeds need to be planted than amount you plan to sell to account for the loss.

Comment: I think i get it now, check the edit i've done and see if it helps. Watch the += part of the code. You have to use it to keep the values else the numSeeds var is reassigned in every loop.

Comment: Hmm I see where you are getting at with the += but the calculation is still coming out off. For example the user wants sell 100 trees and plants 100 seeds. But every year 7% of the remaining seeds die, so in year two he is left with 93 seeds, so on and so forth for 7 years. When 7th comes around, he should be left with 48 seeds (estimate). So initially he needs to plant 150 or so seeds to account for the loss per year and still be able to sell 100 trees when the 7th year comes around

Comment: Can you provide me with an input and the results that the current code gives so i can work it out?

Comment: Try this one out : 

    for(int j = 0; j<7; j++)
        {
            numSeeds += (numTreesPerType[i] - numSeeds) - ((numTreesPerType[i] - numSeeds) * FIR_DIE);
        }

Comment: So example input for numTreesPerType[i] could be 100 and with the += you mentioned it comes out to 751 for numSeedsPerType[i]. A correct output for an input of 100 should be around 150. 7% of 100 = 93, 7% of 93 = 86.49, 7% of 86.49, etc, etc, do that 7 times

Comment: I did, output is still a bit off

Comment: Yes i just checked it, though i think its in the good direction.The value of  FIR_DIE is 7/100?

Comment: Definitely, yes FIR_DIE is 7/100

Comment: Ok i finally found the solution!!

for(int j = 0; j<7; j++) { numSeeds += ((numTreesPerType[i] - numSeeds) * FIR_DIE); }

 After this loop numSeeds will have the number of trees that will die in the next 7 years.